# Android: Set edittext with arraylistvalue

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

Hi i am converting from kilo to stone-pounds, i want to place stones in one edittext and pounds in one edittext , below is my method

```
 public   ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>> kiloTostomepound(int s) {

        int stone = (int) (s * 2.2);
        int stonevalue = stone/14;
        int spound =  (stone % 14);
         arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Integer>>();
        HashMap<String, Integer> h1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        h1.put(STONE,stonevalue);
        h1.put(STONEPOUND, spound);
        arrayList.add(h1);
        return arrayList;

        }
```

i want to get values from the arryalist and set it to edittext.

Doing a below but givinf nullpointerexception

```
edt2.setText(String.valueOf(kiloTostomepound(arrayList.get(0).get(STONE))));
                                edt3.setText(String.valueOf(kiloTostomepound(arrayList.get(1).get(STONEPOUND))));
```

Comment: Do you have multiple edittext or single?

Comment: @RemeesMSyde i have multiple edittexts

Answer (score 0):

The below code traverses through the list and prints key and value.

```
 for (int a =0; a<myList.size();a++)
    {
        HashMap<String, Integer> tmpData = (HashMap<String, Integer>) myList.get(a);
        Set<String> key = tmpData.keySet();
        Iterator it = key.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String hmKey = (String)it.next();
            Integer hmData = (Integer) tmpData.get(hmKey);

            System.out.println("Key: "+hmKey +" & Data: "+hmData);
            it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
        }

    }
```

So if you need the first value try following.

```
    HashMap<String, Integer> tmpData = (HashMap<String, Integer>) myList.get(0);
    Set<String> key = tmpData.keySet();
    Iterator it = key.iterator();

    // Get the first element

    String hmKey = (String)it.next();
    Integer hmData = (Integer) tmpData.get(hmKey);

    // Set the key and value to Edit text

    edt2.setText(hmKey+" "+hmData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your assigning the value to the arrayList variable inside of the method. Hence the

```
kiloTostomepound(arrayList.get(0).get(STONE))
```

Will throw a nullpointer for arrayList.

If I understand your code correctly, the below code should do the trick. But I don't know the input for the kiloTostomepound method.

```
edt2.setText(String.valueOf(kiloTostomepound("INPUT TO METHOD").get(0).get(STONE)));
edt3.setText(String.valueOf(kiloTostomepound("INPUT TO METHOD").get(1).get(STONEPOUND)));
```

This is because your method returns the arrayList with the hashmaps inside.